# Virtual Box:usb device 'Realtek 802.11n NIC' with UUID {cghd hgd ....} busy with previous request. Please try again later

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, kali-linux

I have installed kali linux in **Virtual box 6.1** and when I start my kali machine, my w**ifi adaptor(external adaptor)** turns off.
I have tried using NAT in usb settings but still got same error.
Also tried using usb filtering and selected my adaptor from the list still got same error

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it with following settings:
steps:

1. click on machine
2. click settings
3. click on Network
4. select "bridged adapter" in attached to dropdown menu
5. In Name, select your adapter's company name, in my case it was realtek family...
6. Then in left menu section ,select usb
7. In usb filters section, select your wifi adapter and unselect others.
   That's all you can now use your wifi adaptor, if you want to turn on monitor mode:
   machine->settings->Network->Advanced->Promiscuos mode->Allow VMs